# Asking for support from employer for speaking at a conference

Tags: software-industry, vacation, conferences

I am a software engineer and speaking at an opensource software conference. Although the conference is paying the flight and hotel expenses, I still need to pay for the visa fee.

Also, I wish to attend one of the workshops at the conference (for which I need to pay). I presented at this conference last year as well but my employer refused to pay for the workshop as they believed that the topic of the workshop was not relevant to them (with which I do not agree).

So, while they are fine with paying for the visa application fee, they don't want to pay for the workshop. How do I convince them to support me for both, I feel I am asking them for too much.

And finally, when I am speaking at these conferences, all the attendees get to know about my employer, which is a good thing for them (my employer). So, is it wrong if instead of using my leaves to attend the conference, I ask them to treat as work rather than vacation?

Comment: It's generally not wrong to ask.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading your question wrong, but you seem to be asking multiple things and your core problem isn't clear (at least to me).  For example your last sentence is `So, is it wrong if instead of using my leaves to attend the conference, I ask them to treat as work rather than vacation` but no where else do you mention this issue.  Your employer is paying flight and hotel, but is expecting you to use your vacation time?

Comment: Are you speaking as yourself (working at X) , or as an employee of X ?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Tried to clarify the questions a bit. My employer is not paying for anything, conference is paying for the flights + hotels. I want to ask my employer for visa fee and perhaps if they can also support me to attend a workshop at the conference.

Comment: @Max I am speaking as myself but my biography on the conference website contains my employer's name and my presentation may also contain their name in a slide.

Comment: If your company isn't paying/participating, are you sure that you should be advertising yourself (in your bio and/or slides) as working for the company? It sounds like your company isn't interested, so I wouldn't promote them. It's one thing to direct people to a profile (like LinkedIn) that may have your current employer, but if you are going on your own as an individual, I wouldn't ask the company to pay nor would I promote the employer.

Comment: Were you invited to this conference personally or was the company invited and they sent you to speak on their behalf?

Comment: @ThomasOwens I think rather than not being interested, they are really unaware about the tech conference culture. Pervasive problem with many IT companies in India. That being said, I don't want them to pay for the flights/hotels (because it's more than my monthly salary). If they showed support for visa and workshop, I would happily wear a badge of their name at the conference :)

Comment: @Isaiah3015 I was invited personally. I submitted a presentation proposal about a project I was doing (in my personal time), which got accepted.

Comment: @AbhinavUpadhyay yes, I see that now.  Sorry, I misread that about who was paying for the flight/hotel.  Although since you are commenting using your own account and presumably posted this under an alternative account, you may want to try to clean that up if you are really trying to hide who posted this

Comment: @AbhinavUpadhyay I just approved an edit you suggested, as I assume you and RandomWalker are actually the same person. In the future, please make edits from the account that posted the question so you do not need to request approval. If you would like the two accounts merged, see [this help center page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), or flag the question for moderator attention and request that it be added to your account.

Answer (score 4):

Companies like to sponsor things that will in some way add value to the company, either by bringing in new customers or by making you a more valuable asset.

If you can demonstrate that your presence at the conference will help them make money, they'll probably be more willing to pay for it.  Since you're presenting a project you completed on your own time, you will have to explain how it relates to their business and how presenting it will promote their brand.

With regard to the workshop, if you explain to them the skills you will be gaining and how they will help your work, you may be able to get them to sponsor that as well.  At least at my company, the CEO is a firm believer in education, so if I can demonstrate that a workshop or class will improve my skills and make me more productive, they will most likely be willing to pay for it.  You might consider doing a cost/benefit analysis, estimating the potential monetary gain the company stands to make by sending you to the conference and buying you the workshop vs. the expense of the trip and the cost of your time away from work.

It all depends on how well you make your case.  If you put in a good effort, they should at least appreciate your initiative.  Worst case scenario: they say no.

Answer (score 3):

> when I am speaking at these conferences, all the attendees get to know about my employer, which is a good thing for them.

While this is generally true, it depends on how large the conference is, and how many people you are speaking to. Companies often don't "get" tech conference culture, and some don't really consider this a benefit unless they are reaching hundreds of people.

> So, is it wrong if instead of using my leaves to attend the conference, I ask them to treat as work rather than vacation?

Nothing wrong with this at all, assuming you have permission in advance. This is a common arrangement, where a company may not pay direct expenses, but support your conference speaking by giving you essentially free time off. It's often a good compromise, since getting time off can be difficult, especially if you are speaking at many different events in a year.

**Even if your company is not paying or supporting you, it may still be beneficial to mention them at the conference.** By putting in a good word for your employer, and documenting that, you may be able to get more direct support from your employer down the road at future events.